# glossy surface when importing certains meshes

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to import into Blender 2.9 some .fbx models exported from a 3D software called Noesis.
The issue I'm facing is that the models, once in Blender, look somewhat covered by a glossy/metallic surface, both in solid mode view and in material preview.
This is what I mean:

[image]

while this is what I would expect/like:

[image]

This second picture is done removing the material assigned to the object, to understand if the issue was related to the material itself, and indeed it looks so.

This last picture shows (on the left) the object as shown on Noesis (and how I'd like it to be), and on the right how it looks on Blender. As you can see, that glossy feel is there also in material view.

[image]

I tried importing the object in an online FBX viewer, and it looks glossy too, so I'd say it's not a Blender problem.
Do you know what it could be, and how I could fix that? (assuming that I can't edit any parameter during the export on Noesis)
thank you

blender file:
[image]

Comment: could you please share one part of your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks for the tip, I added the file on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the *Material Viewport Display*, the *Metallic* value is 1, bring it back to 0:

[image]

Also, the material is 100% metallic, bring the value to 0 if you don't want any metallic effect:

[image]

Comment: I tried that (also tried unchecking "custom normals" while importing FBX) but it didn't make any difference except showing the mesh with flat shading)

Comment: Yes my bad, I've edited, I hope it helps?

Comment: yes, totally helped! many thanks. Do you know a way to do a batch edit for all materials?

Comment: no, maybe with code but I don't know anything about coding  ;)

Comment: this:
 
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes:
        mat.metallic = 0
        mat.specular_intensity = 0
        continue
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            n.inputs["Metallic"].default_value = 0
            n.inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0

Comment: oh ok, great then   ;)